# MySQLSelect all columns where the value isn't 0

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have a permissions table where the number of columns can fluctuate. There is a navigation bar on a page that depends on this table. Some people can see some modules, some can not, etc. What I'm wanting to pull off is selecting all the columns where the value isn't 0.

```
table modperm
     uid 1234
     module1 0
     module2 2
     module3 1
     module4 0
     module5 0
     module6 1
...
...
...
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM `modperm` WHERE `uid`='1234' AND value<>0
```

Comment: This is the point where you discover that's a really awful schema to work with and that a one-to-many association between user and permissions would make this really easy. You've violated the [Zero, One or N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) rule.

Comment: Read about database normalization.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is possible, by joining against the system tables in the information_schema database. But a redesign would be a far better idea. Have a table of modules and a table of people, then a link table with a row for each person / module combination that is allowable.

Comment: This is where I see it going. A full-on redesign. The table design was good to see, especially when looking in from phpmyadmin, but now this is... yeah.... not going so well. Well, was worth a shot

Comment: @TechHeadDJ look second demo if it please you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this long query but it may help you.

```
select uid , group_concat(val) as vals from (
SELECT uid, module1 AS val
FROM  modperm
WHERE module1 !=0
and uid = 1234

UNION ALL
SELECT uid , module2 
FROM  modperm 
WHERE module2 !=0
and uid = 1234

UNION ALL
SELECT uid, module3 
FROM  modperm
WHERE module3 != 0
and uid = 1234

UNION ALL
SELECT uid ,module4 
FROM  modperm 
WHERE module4 !=0
AND uid = 1234

UNION ALL
SELECT uid, module5 AS val
FROM  modperm
WHERE module5 !=0
and uid = 1234

UNION ALL
SELECT uid ,module6 
FROM  modperm 
WHERE module6 !=0
and uid =1234
)t
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0faa/5)

if you want show module name

look [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0faa/7)

Comment: Same as the other answer: The problem with this is the dynamic nature of how the table was. I am moving to a one-to-many style table. Maintaining was just getting out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from modperm;
    select uid, 
    case when module1 != 0 then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as module1 ,
    case when module2 != 0 then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as module2 ,
    case when module3 != 0 then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as module3 ,
    case when module4 != 0 then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as module4 ,
    case when module5 != 0 then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as module5 ,
    case when module6 != 0 then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as module6
    .............
    from modperm where uid = 1234;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0faa/13)

Comment: The problem with this is the dynamic nature of how the table was. I am moving to a one-to-many style table. Maintaining was just getting out of hand.